# Fetch all users in active directory in a specified folder

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm doing an application which needs to query active directory and I've been using ldap queries for that purpose.

My problem is that I really cant use `ou=People,dc=pisoftware,dc=com` because the People node name keeps changing because my department name have been changed a lot recently. So in order to avoid the problem of having to do code change each time the name changes then I was wondering if there is any way to query by some sort of a folder id?

For example, maybe I could do `ouid=123456,dc=pisoftware,dc=com`

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you do an ldap query which applies a filter to return back only the objectCategory=person.  You then could target that query at a search base DN, so that it can still return what you want even if the ou/People nodes get renamed/changed.  There is a really good guide to which shows you how to do all this and how the queries work here: http://www.rlmueller.net/ADOSearchTips.htm

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do would be to move the search up the directory hierarchy far enough to encompass wherever the users may be and do:

`myDirectorySearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.SubTree;`

which would then do a recursive sub-tree search throughout AD.